# CollectionView Showing Old Data

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, reusability

I am running into an issue where I am navigating from one UICollectionView to another upon selection of the cell.

The issue is the flashing of previous data. It only happens when I click "back" on the navigation bar. I have included the code where navigation occurs.

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    self.selectedIndexPath = indexPath

    let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: kSecondVCId) as? SecondCollectionViewController
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true) 
}
```

The values are stagnant arrays of values in both views.

Video of issue: https://vimeo.com/263987657

I am using the following library from [GitHub](http://github.com/CezaryKopacz/CKWaveCollectionViewTransition), there is an open issue for this but I'm hoping someone will have thoughts on a possible fix.

Answer (score 0):

The collection view reuses the same cell, so its very simple you have to reset the content before reusing them, else the old cache data will show.

reset the data in UICollecitonViewCell (or) UITableViewCell class using this override function(prepare for reuse)

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
        //just reset the text from here
        self.Button.setTitle(title: "", for: .normal)
        //reset any thing in here which u don't wanna see again
        super.prepareForReuse()
    }
```

Hope this helps, some one. Happy coding !